# Network Interface/Adapter Query

Tags: c++, windows, network-programming

I'm working on a utility that would enable me to identify what interfaces/adapters are available for use on windows, using c++.

My question is are there any functions or programs already available to identify interfaces or adapters(bluetooth, wifi, wifi-direct, nfc) available with simple output (Either I have it or I don't have it, true/false, etc).

While there exists functions that enumerate interfaces (See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) , the data returned from calling these is much too excessive and or unique, I'm simply looking for a true/false on whether the system has bluetooth, wifi, wifi-direct, and/or nfc, before I begin attempting to create sockets / call services from them.

It looks to be an uphill battle at the moment to do this, which makes me curious if this is not already available to me by calling some more convenient functions, or has been done by someone else. I've considered that simply trying to connect could give me an error which I could use as "proof" that there isn't some interface available, but this seems very inappropriate and error prone.

If not I will begin writing it but it's looking like I'd be running through more output than should be necessary for something this simple.

Any information would be useful, and thank you!

EDIT: Jerry Coffin's suggestion works, although I'm waiting on getting hardware to so I can test it against wifi-direct and nfc.

Comment: You could enumerate instances of Win32_NetworkAdapater via WMI (though do note that you'll get instances of "tunneling adapters" and such along with the "real" network adapters).